# $\mathbb{R}$-like spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let us call a topological space $(X,\tau)$ $\mathbb{R}$-*like* if it is homogeneous, connected, $T_2$, has a basis consisting of open sets homeomorphic to $X$, and $|X|>1$.

What is an example of an $\mathbb{R}$-like space that is not homeomorphic to some power of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$?

Comment: Maybe you should modify the question to "not homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$"

Comment: And all open subsets of all normed spaces, and probably some more TVSs.

Comment: Also $\mathbf{R}^2\smallsetminus\mathbf{Q}^2$ satisfies this and is not locally contractible.

Comment: Thanks for these nice examples! Can the first answerer @Qfwfq put his example in an answer so we can close this thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example is $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$